# How to create share post with email button

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create a share by email button for posts in my website.
I have tried bellow code but its not working for me:

```
$email = '<a href="mailto:?subject='.$array['title'].'&body=Check out this site I came across '.$array['url'].'"><img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/social-email.png" /></a>';
```

Please help me in this.

Thank You in advance

Comment: It would be good if you mention what error you are facing.

Comment: Its not open any popup for email address or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax is,

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top">Send Mail</a>
```

Comment: But I want to create share with friends by email functionality so email will be entered by user after click

Comment: So the way you have given subject dynamically, give email address dynamically taking it in variable & using it after `mailto:`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put the email address in the mailto:

Comment: But I want to create share with friends by email functionality so email will be entered by user after click

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as share-link-popup HTML code. If you want to show a popup you'll have to add it yourself with another technique.

You'll need some javascript to create the popup and some server side handling to actually send the email.